# Access & show child table data in Yii

Tags: php, yii

Hi I'm troubling a problem like view child table data based on parent table.

tables structure

topic

```
id  |  name  |  
--------------
 1  |  xyz   |
```

post

```
id  |  topic_id  |  topic_body  |
---------------------------------
 1  |     1      |     abc      |
```

`topic_id` is a `foreign_key`

My work

SiteController

```
$topic = Topic::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'id DESC', 'limit' => 5,'condition'=>'approved=:approved', 'params'=>array(':approved'=>1)));

$this->render('index', array('topic'=>$topic));
```

View

```
<?php
foreach($topic as $topic)
{
    $topics = $topic->title;
    ?>
      <p>
        <a href="view/id/<?php echo $topic->id; ?>">
          <b><?php echo $topics;?></b>
        </a>   
      </p>  
    <?php   
}
?>
```

Now showing topic, but how can I will show topic_body based on topic from child table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a topic model, it is a good idea to define a post model too and create relations between the models.

```
class Post extends CActiveRecord {
    ...
    public function relations() {
        return array(
            'topic'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Topic', 'topic_id')           
        );
    }
}
```

Rewrite Topic Model and add a relation to Post model (One Topic has many posts)

```
class Topic extends CActiveRecord {
    ... 
    public function relations() {
        return array(
            'posts'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Post', 'topic_id')
        );
    }
}
```

Now get your topics and use `->with` to include all posts in the result:

```
$topics = Topic::model()->with('posts')->findAll(array('order'=>'id DESC', 'limit' => 5,'condition'=>'approved=:approved', 'params'=>array(':approved'=>1)));
foreach($topics as $topic){
    echo $topic->title;
    foreach($topic->posts as $post){
         echo $post->topic_body;
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant answer, Thanks :)